# Broadcast Receiver in IntentService (Service has leaked IntentReceiver)

Tags: android

I try to implement an `IntentService` with a `BroadcastReceiver` that reacts on the `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`.

The `IntentService` is supposed to compare Lists whenever `onReceive` is called. I always get the

> "Service has leaked IntentReceiver"

error even though I unregister the `BroadcastReceiver` in `onDestroy()`.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyClass extends IntentService {
    private HashMap<String, List<String>>;
    private WifiManager mWifiManager;
    private WifiReceiver mWifiReceiver; 

public MyClass() {

    super("MyClass");
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    mWifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mWifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    mWifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_SCAN_ONLY,"ScanLock");
    mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    unregisterReceiver(mWifiReceiver);
    mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Here I do my stuff with the scan results
    //should be called every 5 seconds
    }
}
```

Where is the problem in the code?

Why do I keep getting this error?

I still have to learn a lot about Android, but I think the `IntentService` is the right way to go since I do not expect any result from this class. It should just stop when I send a call `stopService()`. This `IntentService` is called by another `IntentService`! Is that a problem?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try registering `BroadcastReceiver` in `OnCreate()` instead of `OnStartCommand()`,

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried that already but the Receiver gets not registered anymore. I created the Wifi Receiver object and registered the Receiver after super.onCreate();

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use onHandleIntent instead of onStartCommand?

Comment: Okay, now it gets registered. Thanks

Comment: This solved my problem, but what is the reason? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

> I try to implement an IntentService with a BroadcastReceiver that reacts on the SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.

This is largely pointless. Your receiver will be registered for a few seconds at most, hopefully.

> I still have to learn a lot about Android, but I think the IntentService is the right way to go since I do not expect any result from this class.

That makes no sense whatsoever. You use an `IntentService` when you have a short bit of work that needs to be performed in a background thread. For example, if you use `AlarmManager` to check for new email messages every 15 minutes, or you have an activity kick off a large file download, you would use `IntentService`.

> It should just stop when I send a call stopService().

You never call `stopService()` on an `IntentService`. The `IntentService` stops itself once `onHandleIntent()` returns. This is why your `BroadcastReceiver` will be removed within seconds -- your `onHandleIntent()` should only be running for seconds.

> This IntentService is called by another IntentService!

This is unlikely to be a good design.

Comment: @CommononsWare.. may be this is irrelevent. but still i need you to look at my question and give me a clue. here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344652/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-field-for-existing-contact-in-android-2-1

Comment: What is a good way achieving this? I want to run a broadcast receiver in background//

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1: Register the receiver in the manifest, using a `<receiver>` element.

Comment: @CommonsWare What if this is a static receiver needs to be registered from class? (BATTERY_CHANGED)

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1: So long as you have something else running for other reasons of value to the user (e.g., a regular `Service`), you can use `registerReceiver()` to listen to that broadcast.